# How to change typing layout for physical keyboard on android tablet?

Tags: samsung, keyboard, external-keyboard, text-layout

I got a QWERTZ keyboard made by Samsung for my Samsung Galaxy tablet because literally I couldn't buy anything else and was lucky to even find this one.

I prefer QWERTY, so I'm wondering how I can switch the keys in android? I can physically swap the keys, but I don't want it to use a QWERTZ layout.

How can I make my physical android QWERTZ keyboard function as a QWERTY keyboard on my samsung Galaxy tablet?

Answer (score 1):

The finer details may differ between OEM's and models, but generally speaking you can use ADB to find and directly modify your device's .kl file.  Note that without root, the changes may or may not persist across device reboot (though you can somewhat improve QoL by using a PC script to automate the process, etc); if you *do* have root, you would need to flash the system partition with the modifications.

Generally speaking, the default keyboard layout file would be `qwerty.kl` and is typically located at `/system/usr/keylayout/qwerty.kl`.  For specifics, you can refer to this [resource](https://wladimir-tm4pda.github.io/porting/keymaps_keyboard_input.html); and here's a [backup](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X3pkFp4UpQ3B9NTgsdsupyFeIWSvlD8d/view) copy for link retention.

Comment: I have root, but I canceled the order of the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

External Keyboard Helper app will enable remapping of your physical keyboard to QWERTY without rooting.

Comment: Your answer can be improved by providing a link to this app.  Thanks!